# Making a webview to accept my specific self-signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview, self-signed

I am running a soft access point and an https server with self-signed certificate on my embedded device.

After connecting to this soft AP, when I send a POST request to this server from my mobile App’s webview, I get the error:

> POST https://192.168.1.123/echo net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Most probably browser is blocking request because the SSL certificate is not signed by a certificate authority (CA) (or may be because this certificate is different than the one for web application running in webview).

Any help please how can I **make webview to accept my specific self-signed certificate?**

Comment: Have you got any update on this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Not yet. I didn't get time to solve it yet. May be in a few days. This link may give you right direction. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#UnknownCa